# Electron app issue: WSL commands from Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, electron, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm new to electron and node.js and am trying to build a user interface in Windows that runs a couple of applications in wsl. I can easily open a terminal using child_process and exec (either bash -c or wsl) but I don't know how to pass app commands in that terminal after that. The commands (source, roslaunch, rosplay) have to be issued in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Got it work as follows from Windows.

```
const child_process = require('child_process')
child_process.exec('start cmd.exe /K bash -c "command-1 && command-2 && command-3"')
```

Of course all of the commands should be available in wsl.